# I am a newbie in mongoose. I want to modify an existing schema by adding fields which are values of another schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongoose-schema

I have created a schema like this for configuring another schema.
It has name field and an array of other fields which can be added in each document.

eg name:type2 
   feild1:value
   frild2:value

In my other schema which has some static feilds, there is a type feild which matches to one of the document in first schema. I want to add the rest of the fields in the array of document of first collection to second collection based on type. How can I do it. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at the MongoDB documentation 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/